# Using Git-tf for iOS project

Tags: tfs, git-tfs, git-tf

I want to use TFS as a version control for developing one of our iPad applications. I followed [this article](http://www.hhogdev.com/~/link.aspx?_id=184AF49EFD1C412EB9C010D694FF9562&_z=z) for configuring my Xcode project.

After doing all the steps mentioned in the blog i am able to `checkin` and `checkout` the whole project. But I am not able to push changed files back to TFS server. More over I am getting following error on executing `git push` command

```
fatal:
https://username@mydomain:8080/tfsprod/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't use `git push`.  You need to `git tf checkin`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EdwardThomson. Yes, i figured that out after banging my head for 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just moving the comments into an answer.

You can't use `git push`. You need to use either `git tf checkin` or `git tf checkin --deep` (if you want a check in per git commit).

Reference documentation for `git tf checkin` [is here](http://gittf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Checkin)